# Captch Integration

Tags: iphone

Is there any particular way to integrate Captch code validation in iPhone application?

is this possible to create captcha? (with or without web-service / any API)

If any kind of external library or any source is required to be imported, then also please let me know.

Any kind of link or source code is available then please suggest me.

Also suggest from where to start to do this, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have searched so far, and have you got anything?

Comment: @vishy.... i don't get any related solutions over google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you probably don't want to hear this, but why do you need captcha on iPhone? It's completely useless since there are no bots or something.

But if you really need it then make some image with white background and then use this code

http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx

to add text to the image... once you'll have this, then just check if the entered string is equal to the randomly generated one on the image and you are good to go.

I didn't find any libraries which could be used as a captcha, so I think this is probably the best solution right now.

Cya,

Nick